# Homogeneous Carnot group, its Lie algebra and Carnot-Carathéodory ball

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde, sub-riemannian-geometry

**Background:** Let the smooth vector fields $X=(X_1,\cdots,X_m)$ define on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and they satisfy the following assumption:

(H1): There is a dilation structure
$$\delta_{t}:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n,\qquad \delta_{t}(x)=(t^{\alpha_{1}}x_{1},\ldots,t^{\alpha_{n}}x_{n}),$$
where $1=\alpha_1\leq\cdots\leq\alpha_n$ are integers, such that
$$ X_{j}(f\circ \delta_{t})=t(X_{j}f)\circ \delta_{t},\qquad \forall~t>0,~ f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n),~j=1,\ldots,m; $$
We denoted by $Q=\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n$ the homogeneous dimension.

(H2):  The vector fields $X_{1},\ldots,X_{m}$ satisfy Hörmander's rank condition at $0$, i.e.,
$$ \text{dim}\{Y(0):~Y\in \text{Lie}(X)\}=n. $$
Here $\text{Lie}(X)$ is the smallest Lie subalgebra of $\mathcal{X}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ containing $X$, where $\mathcal{X}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the Lie algebra of all smooth vector fields in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.09845.pdf, the authors discuss the properties of the vector fields satisfying the assumption above. Set $N=\dim({\rm Lie}(X))$ (item (3.1) in the paper), then we have $N\geq n$. They point out that there are only two case for this kind of the vector fields (page 6):

(1): $N=n$. There exists a homogeneous Carnot group $F$ such that $X_i$ are left invariant on $F$ if and only if $N=n$.

(2): $N>n$. There DOES NOT exist a homogeneous Carnot group $F$ such that $X_i$ are left invariant on $F$ if and only if $N>n$.

Moreover, they introduce that (item (3.14)) under the assumption (H1)(H2), if there exists a homogeneous Carnot group $F$ such that $X_i$ are left invariant on $F$, i.e. $N=n$, then
$$|B(x,r)|=Cr^Q$$
for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $r>0$, where the Carnot-Carathéodory ball $B(x,r)=\{y|d_X(y,x)<r\}$ and $d_X$ is the Carnot-Carathéodory distance deduced by $X$. (For general Hörmander vector fields, this property only holds locally). The conclusions above are also introduced in other references.

**My problem:** under the assumption (H1)(H2), do we have the following?
$$N=n ~~~~~\text{if and only if}~~~~~ |B(x,r)|=Cr^Q,~\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n,~ r>0$$

$N=n$ implies $|B(x,r)|=Cr^Q$ is shown in related reference, including the paper above (item (3.14)). But I hardly see the inverse. In general the inverse case may be wrong, but (H1)(H2) is strong so I guess it may be true. Do you know any information about it? Any help is appreciated.