# Regularity of subelliptic eigenfunction on characteristic domain

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, elliptic-pde, eigenvalues, regularity, sub-riemannian-geometry

**Background:** Consider the Hörmander vector fields $X=(X_1,\cdots,X_m)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and the associated Dirichlet eigenvalue problem
$$-\Delta u:=\sum_{i=1}^mX_i^*X_iu=\lambda u~~\text{on}~\Omega,~~~~u|_{\partial \Omega}=0$$
on an open bounded domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary. Here $X_i^*=-X_i-{\rm div}X$ and under some special condition (say, homogeneouse Hörmander operator, see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396196/homogeneous-carnot-group-its-lie-algebra-and-carnot-carath%c3%a9odory-ball) )$X_i^*=-X_i$.

In Derridj-1972 [Numdam link](http://www.numdam.org/item/AIF_1972__22_2_73_0/), he show that $u\in C^\infty(\Omega\cup\Gamma_0)$, where $\Gamma_0$ is the set of all non-characterist points in $\partial \Omega$. Here non-charaterist point means that for such point $x\in\Gamma_0$, then there is at least one $i\in[1,m]$ such that $X_i\notin T_x(\partial \Omega)$. However, when near the charatierist point, few regularity of $u$ is known. So many research add the condition that the boundary is non-characterist. When it comes to characterist case, the results are not many. We would like to introduce some famous results. Jerison 1981 ([DOI link I](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-1236(81)90040-9), [DOI link II](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-1236(81)90031-8)) tell that the smoothness up to the boundary may fail close to characteristic points. Besides, another study made by C.J. Xu (CPAM 1992, [link](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.678.743&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) shows that if $u$ continuous with some other properties in $\overline{\Omega}$ then $u\in C^\infty(\Omega)$. But as far as we know, the continouity in boundary of $u$ requires the non-characteristic condition. Now we want to know

**Problem:** Can $u$ be continuous at charaterist points? At least, can we have $u\in L^\infty(\Omega)$? One can give more condition to the vector fields if necessary.